# Minimal API delete with multiple params

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

It seems that the `MapDelete` expects a single id to be passed, but my situation, I need to pass a pair of ids. I thought passing a JSON object content would work but it doesn't. Having a POST to act as DELETE can work but it has to have a different path.
Here is my code that results in `the request matched multiple endpoints.`

```
 app.MapPost("/movies/achievements", async (CreateMovieAchievementCommand cmd, ISender sender) =>
 {
     var id = await sender.Send(cmd);
     return TypedResults.Created("/movies/achievements", id);
 });
 app.MapPost("/movies/achievements", async (RemoveMovieAchievementCommand cmd, ISender sender) =>
 {
     await sender.Send(cmd);
     return TypedResults.Ok();
 });
```

I would like to change last one to either `MapDelete` or some how make the 2 posts different enough that it would not result in ambiguity (hoping to keep the URLs the same if possible)

`RemoveMovieAchievementCommand` contains `AchievementId` and `MovieId`

Comment: I think you'd need to have the ids as a query parameter to delete multiple at once. Example: `DELETE /movies/achievements?id=1&id=2&id=3`, and then maybe a singular delete for `DELETE /movies/achievements/1`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined two identical endpoints. Change the one for `RemoveMovieAchievementCommand` to be DELETE which would be much more idiomatic in the REST API paradigm (note that explicit `FromBodyAttribute` is needed):

```cs
app.MapDelete("/movies/achievements",
    async ([FromBody] RemoveMovieAchievementCommand cmd, ISender sender) =>
    {
        await sender.Send(cmd);
        return TypedResults.Ok();
    });
```

Also usually you need only id for delete so you can do something like:

```cs
app.MapDelete("/movies/achievements/{id}", async (idType id, ISender sender) =>
{
    await sender.Send(new RemoveMovieAchievementCommand {Id = id});
    return TypedResults.Ok();
});
```

> `RemoveMovieAchievementCommand` contains `AchievementId` and `MovieId`

I would argue that more RESTfull approach would be moving both to the request path:

```cs
app.MapDelete("/movies/{movieId}/achievements/{achievementId}",
    async (MovieIdType movieId, AchievementIdType achievementId, ISender sender) =>
    {
        await sender.Send(new RemoveMovieAchievementCommand
        {
            AchievementId = achievementId,
            MovieId = movieId
        });
        return TypedResults.Ok();
    });
```

Also see:

- [Is an entity body allowed for an HTTP DELETE request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/2501279)